# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_class.apply(this, arguments)')

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

When trying to instantiate `MyClass()`s I get the following error.

```
s = new MyClass();
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_class.apply(this, arguments)')
```

The is the Class

```
class MyClass
    constructor: (@value = 'defaultValue')
    ….
```

Any idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor needs to be a function so you need to specify `->`:

```
class MyClass
    constructor: (@value = 'defaultValue') ->
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20MyClass%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28@value%20=%20%27defaultValue%27%29%20-%3E%0A%0A%0As%20=%20new%20MyClass%28%29;%0Aconsole.log%28s%29;)